# How to keep function running even when exception is thrown?

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception, jsoup

Say I have several lines of code in a function. Every line has the possibility of throwing a `Null Pointer Exception`. I would like to keep my function executing down the lines **even if** an exception is thrown! But everytime an exception occurs my function returns to the calling function immediately without executing the lines below. I am `try-catch`ing exception within the function. Below is my code:

```
        // get duration
        c.set(17, format(search(doc.select("div.course-info"), "h3", "Duration").select("p").first().ownText()));

        // get start date
        c.set(46, format(doc.select("div.course-info.l-span-7").first().select("p").first().ownText()));

        // get study mode
        c.set(18, format(combine(search(doc.select("div.course-info.l-span-4"), "h3", "Study").select("li"))));

        // get career
        c.set(52, format(doc.select("div#cs-aims-objectives").first().select("div").first().html()));

        // get professional accredition
        c.set(38, format(search(doc.select("div.section-highlight"), "h3", "Professional").select("div").first().html()));

        // get scholarships
        c.set(24, format(search(doc.select("div.media-body"), "h4", "Scholarships").select("div").html()));
```

I would like to keep my function executing down the lines even when an exception occurs at, say line 6. How would I go about it? I could simply set a condition before each line checking if it's null but that would take too much time - **I have 300 lines of code like this...**

Comment: Using null check is the only possible approach.

Comment: @NamanGala Thanks buddy, guess I'll just have to do that.

Comment: Put every call inside try..catch.

Comment: @zgnilec using try-catch does not return control back to the try block. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: I mean add 300x try..catch for each c.set call :-) In C# I would do a method that takes lambda, and swallows exceptions. In java, I think it is possible too (in java 8).

Comment: @zgnilec You probably meant he can try using try-catch with labeled break, because try-catch normally terminates the JVM if the exception is thrown. But that is too complicated anyways

Comment: @zgnilec lol....u r a mad man haha I'd rather write null-checks :) But what you said would definitely work

Comment: Is the NPE really happening inside c.set or is it coming from one of the doc-methods?

Comment: NPE is coming from one of the doc methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do it.  Some thoughtful global find-and-replace along with a bit of keyboard elbow (finger?) grease will have all 300 lines converted to this form much sooner than you might think.

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    CObject c = new CObject(); // Whatever 'c' is, obtained however it needs to be
    Document doc = new Document(); // Obtained however 'doc' needs to be
    setStuff(c, doc, 0);
  }

public void setStuff(CObject c, Document doc, int location) {

int locn = location;
try {
  switch(locn) {
    case 0:
            locn++;
            c.set(17, format(search(doc.select("div.course-info"), "h3", "Duration").select("p").first().ownText()));
    case 1:
            locn++;
            c.set(46, format(doc.select("div.course-info.l-span-7").first().select("p").first().ownText()));
    case 2:
            locn++;
            c.set(18, format(combine(search(doc.select("div.course-info.l-span-4"), "h3", "Study").select("li"))));
    case 3:
            locn++;
            c.set(52, format(doc.select("div#cs-aims-objectives").first().select("div").first().html()));
    case 4:
            locn++;
            c.set(38, format(search(doc.select("div.section-highlight"), "h3", "Professional").select("div").first().html()));
    case 5:
            locn++;
            c.set(24, format(search(doc.select("div.media-body"), "h4", "Scholarships").select("div").html()));
    default:
            return;
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // do whatever with e
    setStuff(c, doc, locn);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, looks decent!

Answer (score 3):

I use an `enum` for patterns like this.

```
enum Thing {

    Duration {

                @Override
                void set(Something c, Doc doc) {
                    c.set(17, format(search(doc.select("div.course-info"), "h3", "Duration").select("p").first().ownText()));
                }
            },
    StartDate {

                @Override
                void set(Something c, Doc doc) {
                    c.set(46, format(doc.select("div.course-info.l-span-7").first().select("p").first().ownText()));
                }
            },
    StudyMode {

                @Override
                void set(Something c, Doc doc) {
                    c.set(18, format(combine(search(doc.select("div.course-info.l-span-4"), "h3", "Study").select("li"))));
                }
            },
    Career {

                @Override
                void set(Something c, Doc doc) {
                    c.set(52, format(doc.select("div#cs-aims-objectives").first().select("div").first().html()));
                }
            },
    ProfessionalAccreditation {

                @Override
                void set(Something c, Doc doc) {
                    c.set(38, format(search(doc.select("div.section-highlight"), "h3", "Professional").select("div").first().html()));
                }
            },
    Scholarships {

                @Override
                void set(Something c, Doc doc) {
                    c.set(24, format(search(doc.select("div.media-body"), "h4", "Scholarships").select("div").html()));
                }
            };

    abstract void set(Something c, Doc doc);
}

public void test() {
    for (Thing t : Thing.values()) {
        try {
            t.set(c, doc);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Log the failure and carry on.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for sharing your knowledge with me! Will keep this in mind and try it out next time! :)